# Minimizing a Concave Function over a convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Here is the optimization problem that I am trying to solve. Thanks in advance for all help/insight provided.

Let $T:[-2,2]^N\to\mathbb{R}_{-}$ be a concave function of its arguments. Given $\mathrm{y}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\alpha_0\leq 0$, consider the maximization problem formulated as follows

$$\mathrm{Minimize}: T(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y})$$
$$\mathrm{Subject\ to}: T(\mathbf{x})\geq \alpha_0$$
where, $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}\triangleq(x_1 . y_1,\ldots,x_N . y_N)$. Can we say anything about the classification of the optimal solution(s)? Specifically, can we argue that the optimal solution $\mathbf{x}^\star$ should be such that $|x^\star_i|$ attains the maximum admissible value where $i=\arg\max_{n}|y_n|$?

Best,

Mustafa